# How Can I show my own text when no node is visible

Tags: delphi, virtualtreeview

I use a virtualtreeview, and I want to show differents messages into the component, regardless columns, when no node visible.

Have you some idea to do this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write a handler for the `OnPaintBackground` event. For example:

```
procedure TForm1.VirtualStringTreePaintBackground(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree;
  TargetCanvas: TCanvas; R: TRect; var Handled: Boolean);
begin
  if Sender.VisibleCount = 0 then
  begin
    Handled := True;
    TargetCanvas.TextOut(10, 10, 'List has no visible nodes.');
  end;
end;
```

If you are interested in showing a text when the control is empty (not just when their nodes are hidden), you can use the `EmptyListMessage` property.

Comment: Nice, thank you.
I have just a problem with the VisibleCount property witch is invalid, but I create my own function.

Comment: You're welcome! Well, you must be using some ancient version. I would suggest you to update to the recent version.